# Tensorflow2 Object Detection API Loading saved_model.pb and use for prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I trained a model and saved it. Now I want to go back that model. I have a checkpoint file, saved_model file (assets,variables and saved_model.pb),pipeline.config and labelmap.pbtxt. How can I load this model and make predict? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your model by using
`detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load("/path/to/saved_model")` and run inference using
`detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)`.
To run inference and visualize:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils

detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load("/path/to/saved_model")
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'path/to/labels.pbtxt'
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)
IMAGE_PATHS = ["/path/to/test/image1","/path/to/test/image2"]
def load_image_into_numpy_array(path):
    return np.array(Image.open(path))


for image_path in IMAGE_PATHS:
    print('Running inference for {}... '.format(image_path), end='')
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
    input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
    # input_tensor = np.expand_dims(image_np, 0)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                   for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()
    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'],
          detections['detection_classes'],
          detections['detection_scores'],
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          max_boxes_to_draw=200,
          min_score_thresh=.6,
          agnostic_mode=False)
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
    plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
    print('Done')
plt.show()
```

Please refer to: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/inference_tf2_colab.ipynb

Comment: ValueError: Python inputs incompatible with input_signature:
  inputs: (
    [[[  4   4   4 ...   4   4   4]
  [  4   4   4 ...   4   4   4]
  [  4   4   4 ...   4   4   4]
  ...
  [234 234 234 ... 235 235 235]
  [234 234 234 ... 235 235 235]
  [234 234 234 ... 235 235 235]]])
  input_signature: (
    TensorSpec(shape=(1, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.uint8, name='input_tensor')).

Comment: Hello. I'm taking this error. What can be done input tensor shape: (1,3072,3072)

Comment: You can reshape your inputs accordigly. What is the shape of your current inputs?
Use `input_tensor.shape` to check it's shape. Your model expects a shape of (1, X, Y, 3). If your input is something like (X,Y,3), you must use the commented out line in my original answer: `input_tensor = np.expand_dims(input_tensor, 0)`

Comment: input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
    print(input_tensor.shape)  # (3072,3072)
    input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
    print(input_tensor.shape)  # (1,3072,3072)

Comment: ValueError: Python inputs incompatible with input_signature:
  inputs: (
    tf.Tensor(
[[[  4   4   4 ...   4   4   4]
  [  4   4   4 ...   4   4   4]
  [  4   4   4 ...   4   4   4]
  ...
  [234 234 234 ... 235 235 235]
  [234 234 234 ... 235 235 235]
  [234 234 234 ... 235 235 235]]], shape=(1, 3072, 3072), dtype=uint8))
  input_signature: (
    TensorSpec(shape=(1, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.uint8, name='input_tensor')).

Comment: Your inputs do not have an RGB channel. The 3 in the end reprensents that. So your inputs -as the signature tells- should be in shape of (1, X, Y, 3). Right now, yours are (1, X, Y)